# Join multiple columns from two data frames with different column names in each

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have the following problem: I have two excel files imported into R and I want to replace the data in the empty data frame that has the correct column names with data from the phone populated dataframe that has the wrong column names as well as other columns I don't need. I have a mapping key where variable name = wrong variable name. I figure the best way to do this is I use a join such as

```
df <- right join(keepdf, wrongdf, by= c('variable name' = 'wrong variable name', keep=FALSE)
```

My question is how to pass many pairs of names into the by= parameter. I have tried nested for loops with the respective variable names in each list but it hasn't worked. Also if anyone has a suggestion on how to accomplish this better I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if the code you put in top is the exact code you are trying to run you need to fix the function.  You also need to load dplyr.

```
### if you want to keep the keep df it should be a left_join###
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(keepdf, wrongdf, by= c('variable name' = 'wrong variable name'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is clearly not the exact code because the code does not include the loading of the data frames from excel or even the instantiation of the data frames "keepdf" and "wrongdf"

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example